# Nullpointerexception due to proguard for java.io.StringReader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

```
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:435)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:138)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:101)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at al.instantiateItem(HomeScreen.java:533)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:442)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.vserv.kasakusuk.HomeScreen.a(HomeScreen.java:444)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at ai.run(HomeScreen.java:401)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-17 19:00:53.681: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i got this exception when i create a build with proguard enabled and run on device.
can anyone help in this issue?
what i may be missing in proguard config file?

Comment: show your relevant code pls

Comment: What is missing in your config? Well do you have one?

Comment: txtvw.settext(Html.fromHtml(string_with_html_tags)); at line HomeScreen.java:533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of Html.fromHtml has become null. Presumably, your program is reading it from a resource that can't be found in the processed code. For instance, the package name of the obfuscated class may have changed, while the package name of the resource file may have remained the same.

You can find some suggestions in the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [MissingResourceException or NullPointerException](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#missingresourceexception)

Comment: Well done @Eric !  A very solid answer to an extremely incomplete question.

Comment: @Eric: good answer. but im not using resource string as an argument. that text is parsed from online feed. actually im working on news app. how can you help?

Comment: Hi @Eric what is solution?